# OpenEdx error while running python code in Codejail Plugins using Dockerize container services

Tags: django, matplotlib, docker-compose, openedx, edx

I have installed a stack of OpexEDX platform using Tutor and installed OpexEdx "Codejail" plugin using below link

`pip install git+https://github.com/edunext/tutor-contrib-codejail`

https://github.com/eduNEXT/tutor-contrib-codejail

I am facing a problem during working on the code jail while importing python matplotlib library.

importing the same library inside codejail container is working fine. the only problem is import through OpnexEdx code block.   > advance black > problem.
I have already installed the Codejail and Matplotlib on docker.

I have to run this code. which gives error

```
<problem>
<script type="loncapa/python">
import matplotlib
</script>
</problem>
```

`import os` works fine
but getting error while
`import matplotlib`

detail of current stack:

- open edx version : openedx-mfe:14.0.1
- code jail version :  codejailservice:14.1.0
- please see the error message below

`cannot create LoncapaProblem block-v1:VUP+Math101+2022+type@problem+block@3319c4e42da64a74b0e40f048e3f2599: Error while executing script code: Couldn't execute jailed code: stdout: b'', stderr: b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File &#34;jailed_code&#34;, line 19, in <module>\n    exec(code, g_dict)\n  File &#34;<string>&#34;, line 66, in <module>\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 921, in <module>\n    dict.update(rcParams, rc_params_in_file(matplotlib_fname()))\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 602, in matplotlib_fname\n    for fname in gen_candidates():\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 599, in gen_candidates\n    yield os.path.join(get_configdir(), \'matplotlibrc\')\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 239, in wrapper\n    ret = func(**kwargs)\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 502, in get_configdir\n    return get_config_or_cache_dir(_get_xdg_config_dir())\n  File &#34;/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py&#34;, line 474, in get_config_or_cache_dir\n    tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=&#34;matplotlib-&#34;)\n  File &#34;/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.6_sandbox/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py&#34;, line 347, in mkdtemp\n    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)\n  File &#34;/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.6_sandbox/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py&#34;, line 117, in sanitize_params\n    dir = gettempdir()\n  File &#34;/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.6_sandbox/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py&#34;, line 286, in gettempdir\n    tempdir = get_default_tempdir()\n  File &#34;/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.6_sandbox/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py&#34;, line 218, in _get_default_tempdir\n    raise FileNotFoundError(_errno.ENOENT,\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in [\'/tmp\', \'/var/tmp\', \'/usr/tmp\', \'/tmp/codejail-lbfd69da\']\n' with status code: 1. For more information check Codejail Service logs.`

Codejail service logs are as follows:

`{"log":"[pid: 6|app: 0|req: 20/39] 172.18.0.10 () {36 vars in 483 bytes} [Tue Nov 22 11:24:59 2022] POST /api/v0/code-exec =\u003e generated 1978 bytes in 742 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 73 bytes (1 switches on core 0)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-22T11:25:00.151315626Z"} {"log":"2022-11-22 11:26:23,304 INFO 9 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:52 - Running problem_id:53fbaa04859f41989ab967c15a12c013 jailed code for course_id:course-v1:VUP+Math101+2022 ...\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-22T11:26:23.30489438Z"} {"log":"2022-11-22 11:26:23,343 INFO 9 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:73 - Jailed code was executed in 0.03849988000001758 seconds.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-22T11:26:23.343618965Z"} {"log":"[pid: 9|app: 0|req: 20/40] 172.18.0.10 () {36 vars in 483 bytes} [Tue Nov 22 11:26:23 2022] POST /api/v0/code-exec =\u003e generated 73 bytes in 40 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 71 bytes (1 switches on core 0)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-22T11:26:23.344178308Z"} {"log":"2022-11-23 04:15:24,786 INFO 6 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:52 - Running problem_id:3319c4e42da64a74b0e40f048e3f2599 jailed code for course_id:course-v1:VUP+Math101+2022 ...\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T04:15:24.786287416Z"} {"log":"2022-11-23 04:15:25,582 ERROR 6 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:70 - Error found while executing jailed code.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T04:15:25.582527974Z"} {"log":"[pid: 6|app: 0|req: 21/41] 172.18.0.10 () {36 vars in 483 bytes} [Wed Nov 23 04:15:24 2022] POST /api/v0/code-exec =\u003e generated 1978 bytes in 798 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 73 bytes (1 switches on core 0)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T04:15:25.583132326Z"} {"log":"2022-11-23 06:00:15,150 INFO 9 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:52 - Running problem_id:3319c4e42da64a74b0e40f048e3f2599 jailed code for course_id:course-v1:VUP+Math101+2022 ...\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T06:00:15.15073834Z"} {"log":"2022-11-23 06:00:15,891 ERROR 9 [codejailservice.app] code_exec_service.py:70 - Error found while executing jailed code.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T06:00:15.8916806Z"} {"log":"[pid: 9|app: 0|req: 21/42] 172.18.0.10 () {36 vars in 483 bytes} [Wed Nov 23 06:00:15 2022] POST /api/v0/code-exec =\u003e generated 1978 bytes in 742 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 73 bytes (1 switches on core 0)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-11-23T06:00:15.892225441Z"}`

Comment: https://github.com/eduNEXT/codejailservice/issues/17

A workaround is discussed here . it is a temporary solution.

Comment: https://github.com/eduNEXT/tutor-contrib-codejail/issues/29